# Is there a command to teleport behind a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any command to teleport me just 3 blocks behind a player? I haven't found any command to do this and there doesn't seem to be anything about this question, I'm quite sure that this could be done with the /execute command but I don't know how to it (I don't have much knowledge about the /execute command so this is why I'm asking this question) also I'm playing on 1.16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
/execute at PLAYER_2 run tp @s ^ ^ ^-3
```

This will execute at them and put you 3 blocks behind where they are looking. Beware if they are looking up that you will be teleported into the ground.

Comment: You can use `/execute rotated` to make sure it does not include pitch, thus preventing them from going into the ground